# HTML Webpack Plugin will not compile as Thymeleaf variables are undefined

Tags: webpack, thymeleaf, html-webpack-plugin

When Webpack compiles my app which contains the below HTML, it complains the `theme` variable is undefined.

Here is my `index.html` file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
</head>
<body th:class="${theme}">
    <div id="root"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is the error I get:

```
Failed to compile.

Error in Template execution failed: ReferenceError: theme is not defined

- loader.js:4 eval
/src/main/resources/templates/index.html?./~/html-webpack-plugin/lib/loader.js:4:10
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put this in :

webpack.config

```
new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
     template: './index.ejs',
     filename: './index.html',
     minify: { collapseWhitespace: true },
     csrf: '${_csrf.token}',
}),
```

in your index.ejs file put :

```
<meta name="_csrf" th:content="<%= htmlWebpackPlugin.options.csrf %>"/>
```

Answer (score 4):

My workaround: replace `$` to `<%="$"%>`

Answer (score 3):

Same error here. I've found [this issue](https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin/issues/362) and you have just to make webpack use 'html-loader' like this:

```
new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
    template: '!!html-loader!index.html'
})
```

PS: Don't forget to install it before with npm ;)

Comment: can you please explain how to use this into vue.config.js?