# Vue js CLI 3 fail to build with Thymeleaf syntax

Tags: spring-boot, webpack, thymeleaf, vue-cli

I'm working on a little multi-page application based on Vue.js CLI 3 and Spring boot for the backend.

I read the [official doc](https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#pages) to build a multi page, so my `vue.config.js` looks like:

```
module.exports = {
    outputDir: 'target/dist',
    pages: {
        home: {
            entry: 'src/home/home.js',
            template: 'src/home/home.html',
            filename: 'home.js'
        },
        otherPage: {...}
    }
}
```

Everything works fine, until I add some Thymeleaf syntax in my templates (e.g. with placholders `${text}`). The build fails because of the `${}` placeholders which are not resolved (I don't know which loader or plugin try to resolve thoses placeholders, I use the standard vue-cli webpack project structure..).

Is there a way to configure webpack in order to ignore the Thymeleaf syntax and to not trying to resolve thoses placeholders?

Comment: use html-loader. But it won't be enough. Also filename is the destination path. So it should be html

Answer (score 1):

I replaced `$` by `<%="$"%>` as [workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46033326/html-webpack-plugin-will-not-compile-as-thymeleaf-variables-are-undefined).

But it's not work for `<script></script>`

```
<script>
    var user = <%="$"%>{user};
</script>
```

Then I found [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25687816/setting-up-a-javascript-variable-from-spring-model-by-using-thymeleaf)

```
<script th:inline="javascript">
/*<![CDATA[*/
    var user = /*[[<%="$"%>{user}]]*/ 'default';
/*]]>*/
</script>
```